# Geometric Brownian motion with stochastic drift

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have the following set of differential equations:

$$ \left\{\begin{array}{ll}  
        dr(t) = a(\theta(t) - r(t))dt + \sigma_r dW_1(t)  \\
        dS(t) = r(t)S(t)dt + \sigma_SS(t)dW_2(t)
    \end{array} \right.$$
where $W_1(t)$ and $W_2(t)$ are correlated Brownian motions with correlation coefficient $\rho$, the function $\theta(t)$ is deterministic, $a \in \mathbb{R}$,   $\sigma_r > 0$ and $\sigma_S >0$ are given constants. I would like to find an expression for $\mathbb{E}[S(t)]$. 
I got that $$ r(t) = e^{-at}\left(r(0) + a\int_0^t\theta(s)e^{as}ds + \sigma_r\int_0^te^{as}dW_1(s) \right)$$ $$ S(t) = S(0)\exp\left\{ \int_0^t r(x)dx - \frac{\sigma_S^2t}{2} + \sigma_SW_2(t)\right\} $$ so I also calculated $$ \int_0^tr(x) dx = \frac{r(0)}{a}(1-e^{-at}) + \int_0^t \theta(s)(1-e^{a(s-t)})ds + \frac{\sigma_r}{a}\int_0^t(1-e^{a(s-t)})dW_1(s) $$

Comment: So far so good. Now you are able to compute the expectation. To this end, observe that $\frac{\sigma_r}{a}\int_0^t(1-e^{a(s-t)})dW_1(s) + \sigma_S W_2(t)$ is a centered Gaussian random variable, so you just only need to find its expectation.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about whether the variables $ \frac{\sigma_r}{a}\int_0^t(1-e^{a(s-t)})dW_1(s) $  and $\sigma_S W_2(t)$ still had a joint normal distribution. So the covariance matrix would be $$ \Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\sigma_r^2}{a^2}\int_0^t (1-e^{a(s-t)})^2ds & \frac{\rho \sigma_r \sigma_s}{a}\int_0^t (1-e^{a(s-t)})ds  \\ \frac{\rho \sigma_r \sigma_s}{a}\int_0^t (1-e^{a(s-t)})ds & \sigma_S^2t
\end{pmatrix} $$ which I use to determine $ \mathbb{E} [\exp\left\{\frac{\sigma_r}{a}\int_0^t(1-e^{a(s-t)})dW_1(s) + \sigma_S W_2(t) \right\} $.

Comment: Correct. It would be perfect if you put this as an answer and accept it.